# view to list already added referenced nodes to all content types by user

Tags: views, nodes, entities

I have a content type of DELIVERY, and another content type of BOOK. Now each user has 3 DELIVERY content types that they are the author of. What i do is then edit a users DELIVERY content and add a BOOK to it (i have added a entity reference, referencing BOOK in DELIVERY).

All works fine, what i want to do is create a View, so that when i edit a users DELIVERY it lists the BOOKS i have already assigned to all the other DELIVERY's from that user. is this possible? been playing around with it but cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

OK i managed to do it, for anyone curious heres how i did it:

I created a new View
I filtere it to show content of type DELIVERY
i added 2 Relationships
First relationship being the BOOK Reference field and the other being Author relationship
I then added a Contexiual Filter of NID and set it to default value and NID From URL
That was it, and i added the Book ref field to show the books